# If $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\ \forall i=1,...,k$, how to prove $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subseteq\text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_l\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\  \forall i=1,...,k$ and $y_1,...,y_l$ are vectors in vector space V, how to prove $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subseteq\text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_l\}$?

Since $x_i\in \text{ span }\{y_1,...y_l\}\  \forall i=1,...,k$, $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}=a_1y_1+...+a_ly_l$, meaning any vectors in $\text{ span }(X)$ can be linearly combined by vectors in $\text{ span }(Y)$. Therefore $\text{ span }\{x_1,...,x_k\}\subseteq \text{ span }\{y_1,...,y_1\}$.

Could someone please improve the proof?

Comment: It's better to explicitly write out the "any vector in $\text{span}(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$" by $x$, say. Writing $$"\text{span}\{x_1, \ldots, x_k\} = a_1y_1  + \cdots + a_ly_l"$$ is not rigorously correct as two objects at each side of the equality are not the same type objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_i \in$ span$\{y_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,y_l\} \forall i\in[1,k]$, then that means any $x_i$ can be represented as the following:

$$x_i=a_1y_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_ly_l$$  for at least one $a_j\neq 0$ where $j\in [1,l]$
That means that any linear combination of the vector $x_i$

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_kx_k=span\{x_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_k\}\subseteq a_1y_1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+a_ly_l=span\{y_1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,y_l\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$
x_i=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\beta_{ij}y_j
$$
Then, if $z$ belongs to the span of $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$, you have
$$
z=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_ix_i
=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{l}\beta_{ij}y_j\biggr)
=\sum_{j=1}^l\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\beta_{ij}\biggr)y_j
$$